# initWithContentsOfURL leaks memory within NSOperation subclass. Anyone else seeing this?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multithreading, nsoperation

I have been living on Instruments for last few hours staring at a puzzling memory leak. I have isolated it to this single line of code in an NSOperation subclass I wrote:

```
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURLString]];
```

Periodically this will leak 3500 bytes. Is anyone else seeing this? If so, is there a work around?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Here is the relevant section of code within the main() body of my NSOperation subclass:

```
- (void)main {

// ...

NSData *sequenceData = 
[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:concatenatedURLString]];

NSString *sequenceString = 
[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[sequenceData bytes] length:[sequenceData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
self.chromosome, @"chromosome",
[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.basepairStart], @"basepairStart", 
[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.basepairEnd], @"basepairEnd", 
sequenceData, @"sequenceData", 
sequenceString,  @"sequenceString", 
nil];

[sequenceData   release];
[sequenceString release];

[self.target performSelectorOnMainThread:self.action withObject:result waitUntilDone:NO];


}
```

As you can see sequenceData and sequenceString are properly released. Also, I have confirmed that all ivars of this subclass (chromosome. etc.) are properly memory managed.

-Doug

Comment: We ned to see more code to know anything useful. How are you cleaning up? If you're not, then there's the problem right there!

Comment: Whoops. I just added all relevant code.

Comment: Are you running this in Instruments with NSZombieEnabled? That can cause false "leaks" to show up.

Comment: nail,

I did have NSZombieEnabled defined as an environment variable. I removed it, still no joy.

Note: I only see the mems leak on device. The simulator shows no mem leak. Sigh.

Comment: I am also experiencing leaks with NSOperation-based networking code.  My question, which may be related to yours, is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337250/iphone-confused-about-leaks-within-my-nsoperation

Answer (score 0):

You have to release or autorelease myData, otherwise it will leak according to the [Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Just added the relevant code showing proper releasing of the NSData instance.