# Iphone -- Confused about leaks within my NSOperation

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsoperation

My app has an NSOperation class called ServerRequest that handles networking tasks.  According to instruments, it is leaking like crazy.  Additionally, instruments says the code that builds the request is leaking, even though that is not an NSOperation.  But I have followed Apple's advice in terms of setting up an autorelease pool, so I don't understand what could be the matter.  Can anyone help?

A portion of my code is below:

```
-(void) main {
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 self.data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];  // lots of leakage here
 [self postResult]; // leakage here too
 [pool release];
}
```

and the postResult method (which is not leaking):

```
-(void) postResult {
// error handling code here

 if (![self isCancelled])
 {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSMutableDictionary *resultDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  if (self.data!=nil)
   [resultDictionary setObject:self.data forKey:kDataKey];
  if (self.response!=nil)
   [resultDictionary setObject:self.response forKey:kResponseKey];
  if (self.error!=nil)
   [resultDictionary setObject:self.error forKey:kErrorKey];
  NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
  NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName: kDownloadCompleteName object: self userInfo: resultDictionary];
  [resultDictionary release];
  [center postNotification: notification];

  [pool drain];
 }
}
```

Lastly, dealloc:

```
- (void) dealloc {
 self.request = nil;
 self.data = nil;
 self.mutableData = nil;
 if (!self.error)
  self.error = nil;
 if (!self.response)
  self.response = nil;
 [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Hm. `if( !self.error ) self.error = nil` seems not to look right to my tired eyes... Likewise for the `self.response` stuff.

Comment: This is why I prefer `if (self.error != nil)` .. it is more to the point and has less magic.

Comment: In any case using property setters to release ivars just looks incorrect.

Comment: @KennyTM: Hm. I'm fine with that; but only releasing an ivar if its already `nil` is a little bit odd...

Comment: You're right, that's weird.  I changed it to release it if it is non-nil . . . and the app now crashes at that line, i.e.

    if (self.response !=nil)
      [self.response release];  // crashes here.

response is synthesized with @property (nonatomic, retain)

Comment: Summarizing the situation.  If I release my response variable, the app. crashes due to over-release.  If I don't release it, instruments reports a leak.

Could instruments be giving me a false positive?  How would I tell?

Answer (score 0):

Some recommend avoiding the `self.var = nil` setter approach to releasing variables in the `-dealloc` deconstructor.

Have you tried the old tried-and-true `[var release], var = nil` approach?

Comment: Yes.  It's still the case that if I release it, the program crashes, saying that I am sending a message to a deallocated object.  But if I don't release it, instruments shows a leak.

Comment: I'll see if I can find the blog posting that discusses why this is a bad idea. Maybe someone who knows the post I'm referring to can also post if they find it first.